# Parsing character to time in R

Tags: r

I have data such as

```
a = c("13:10.3","20:40.4")
```

I want to convert it to time. I tried the following two techniques,

```
as.POSIXlt(head(a), format= "%S:%M.%H")
```

but getting `2016-03-04 03:10:13 PST` as output. I dont want the date here and also the time zone. want only the time.

I also tried,

```
chron(head(a), format = "%ss:%mm.%h") or chron(head(a), format = "%S:%M.%h")
```

But getting the following error,

```
Error in parse.format(format) : unrecognized format %ss:%mm.%h
```

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Comment: There is no class for *just* time in (base) R. Why not just ignore the date component of a datetime object?

Comment: @nrussell if you dont mind, can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Well you already did it: `as.POSIXlt(head(a), format= "%S:%M.%H")`. I'm saying just pretend the date and timezone components aren't there.

Comment: Or you can use the `ITime` class provided by `data.table` I think: `data.table::as.ITime(c("13:10.3","20:40.4"), format = "%H:%M.%S")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chron package has the `"times"` class:

```
library(chron)
a <- c("13:10.3","20:40.4")

tt <- times(chartr(".", ":", a))
tt
## [1] 13:10:03 20:40:04

tt + 1/24 # add one hour
## [1] 14:10:03 21:40:04
```

Answer (score 1):

`POSIXlt` combines both date and time, but you can use `format()` to only show time part:

```
format(as.POSIXlt(head(a), format= "%S:%M.%H"), format= "%S:%M.%H")
[1] "13:10.03" "20:40.04"
```

Comment: this one converts it back to character. What do we do to have it as a time?

Comment: class(format(as.POSIXlt(head(a), format= "%S:%M.%H"), format= "%H:%M:%S"))

"character"

Comment: as @nrussel wrote, there is no time object, which is usually not much of a problem. And since your question was that you only wanted the time part shown, then I consider my answer is OK. Alternatively, you can represent the time with an integer which would be the number of seconds from midnight...

Comment: `format(strptime(a,"%H:%M.%S"), "%H:%M:%S")` does the same and is somewhat shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lubridate` package, which has several types of objects besides POSIXlt and POSIXct for storing time objects.

For instance, you can parse manually to avoid any conversion to POSIX:

```
library(lubridate)
lapply(strsplit(c("13:10.3","20:40.4"), '[:.]'), 
       function(x){seconds(x[1]) + minutes(x[2]) + hours(x[3])}
)
```

which returns two of `lubridate`'s `Period` objects:

```
[[1]]
[1] "3H 10M 13S"

[[2]]
[1] "4H 40M 20S"
```

If your data is in a nicer format to start, it has a lot of very nice helper functions to simplify:

```
> hms(c("13:10.3","20:40.4"))
[1] "13H 10M 3S" "20H 40M 4S"
```

Comment: Can we just have this as a normal time format?

Comment: Objects are stored in a particular normalized format. You can format them to the way you want, but in doing so you coerce them to strings, which you don't seem to want. Generally, formatting should be your last step.

Comment: The `chron` package's `times` object may be more to your liking. Parsing is a pain with periods, though, so you'll have to replace them: `library(chron); chron(times. = gsub('\\.', ':', c("13:10.3","20:40.4")), format = c(times = 's:m:h'))`